# How does Photoshop convert type format to a rasterized layer?

Tags: python, c, photoshop

I have been thinking of fonts quite recently. I find the whole process of a keystroke converted to a character displayed in a particular font quite fascinating. What fascinates me more is that each character is not an image but just the right bunch of pixels switched on (or off).

In Photoshop when I make a text layer, I am assuming it's like any other text layer in a word processor. There's a glyph attached to a character and that is displayed. So technically it's still not an 'image' so as to speak and it can be treated as a text in a word processor. However, when you rasterize the text layer, an image of the text is created with the font that was used. Can somebody tell me how Photoshop does this? I am assuming there should be a lookup table with the characters' graphics which Photoshop accesses to rasterize the layer.

I want to kind of create a program where I generate an image of the character that I am pressing (in C or Python or something like that). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe currently has publicly accessible documentation for [the Photoshop file format](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/). I've needed to extract information from PSD files (about a year ago, but actually the ancient CS2 version of Photoshop) so I can warn you that this isn't light reading, and there are some parts (at least in the CS2 documentation) that are incomplete or inaccurate. Usually, even when you have file format documentation, you need to do some reverse engineering to work with that file format.

Even so, see [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577409_60077) for info about the `TySh` chunk from Photoshop 6.0 (not sure at a quick glance if it's still the current form for text - "type" to Photoshop).

Anyway, yes - text is stored as a sequence of character codes in memory and in the file. Fonts are basically collections of vector artwork, so that text can be converted to vector paths. That can be done either by dealing with the font files yourself, using on operating system call (there's definitely one for Windows, but I don't remember the name, it's bugging me now so I might figure it out later), or using a library.

Once you have the vector form, that's basically Bezier paths just like any other vector artwork, and can be rendered the same way.

Or to go directly from text to pixels, you just ask e.g. Windows to draw the text for you - perhaps to a memory DC (device context) if you don't want to draw to the screen.

[FreeType](http://freetype.org/) is an open source library for working with fonts. It can definitely render to a bitmap. I haven't checked but it can probably convert text to vector paths too - after all it needs to do that as part of rendering to pixels anyway.

[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) is another obvious library to look at for font handling and much more, but I've never used it directly myself.

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) is yet another obvious library to look at, and uses a memory-DC scheme similar to that for Windows, though I don't remember exact class/method names. Converting text to vectors might be outside wxWidgets scope, though.